# Localize Model in Identity .NET 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am translating my site from English to French.
For the moment everything is going well except for the translation in the Identity part of the site.
I am currently trying to translate the login part of the site.
I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2
Le name est: namespace cae.website.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account

```
public class InputModel
{
    [ExRequired]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email", Prompt = "example@outlook.com")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ExRequired]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password", Prompt = "******")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}



        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLocalization(opts =>
            {
                opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
            });
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(opts =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en"),
                    new CultureInfo("fr")
                };

                opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
                // Formating numbers, dates, etc.
                opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                // UI strings that we have localized
                opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            });
}





public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
    app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
}
```

I have a Resource folder where I put my .resx file but the translation is not done. What am I missing to make it work? I haven't found much on the net.

[image]

Comment: Your missing a lot of code. Show us all the steps you took here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @Train Actually i did everything and it works pretty well. I just don't know how to do for the Identity part.

Comment: Could you share your Login.cshtml and the screenshot about your result?

Answer (score 0):

In your startup file use below localization settings:

```cs
services.AddMvc()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
        ...
```

or

```cs
services.AddMvc()
        .AddMvcLocalization()
        ...
```

For more details see [`AddMvcLocalization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvclocalizationmvccorebuilderextensions?view=aspnetcore-2.2), [`AddDataAnnotationsLocalization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcdataannotationsmvccorebuilderextensions.adddataannotationslocalization?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and this [step-by-step tutorial](http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/10-Developing_Multicultural_Web_Application) can help.

Comment: It is already there.. Sorry if i didnt showed it. It works for the classic part. It just doesnt work for the Identity

Comment: @Korpin just noticed that `Pages` level is missed in the resources tree `Resources\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Login.xx.resx`

Comment: btw, just wondering about `[ExRequired]`, is it your implementation? cuz it looks similar to what I've developed in [`ExpressLocalization`](https://github.com/LazZiya/ExpressLocalization/wiki/DataAnnotations-Localization-Using-Express-Attributes) :)

Comment: Sorry, for the very late reply but yeah it was yours lol